# Uno Platform: The imported project was not found

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, uno-platform

I've just installed uno platform and I'm having a bit of an issue. Whenever I create new projects the projects come with errors. I wasn't able to find info about this specific kind of errors on the website. I've also enabled long paths just in case. Any idea what's causing this?
[image: Check]
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using spaces in the project name. Uno does not currently support this.
I also strongly discourage the use of spaces in the name for any other C# projects to avoid unnecessary problems. The standard C# naming contains a dot, for example: `Ryder.Display` or simply `RyderDisplay`.